# WebStorm: Unresolved variable when using export * from

Tags: webstorm

WebStorm 2017.2.2

When I try to export modules using `export * as name from` WebStorm cannot resolve objects when it is imported in another file.

Example:

```
// file1.js
export const foo = () => {};
export const bar = () => {};

// file2.js
export * as file1 from './file1';


// file3.js
import * as file2 from './file2';

console.log(file2.file1.foo); // Unresolved variable file1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Known issue, please follow [WEB-20955](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-20955) for updates